# Blazor Closes the div tag on a conditionally div wrapper

Tags: c#, html, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side

Im trying to wrap one of my components on some specific tag based on some conditions.

To make it simple lets say that i have a

```
<div class="inner-class">
    this must be in inner-class div and wrapped in some-class div
</div>
```

And if 'condition' == true then it should wrap it in another div the result should be like this

```
<div class="wrapper-class">
    <div class="inner-class">
        this must be in inner-class div and wrapped in some-class div
    </div>
</div>
```

And before you say, use if-else method. i must say no. because the tag and the class in it is dynamic so i cant write it like that.

What i tried to do is

```
@if (condition)
{
    @:<div class="wrapper-class">
}
    <div class="inner-class">
        this must be in inner-class div and wrapped in some-class div
    </div>
}
@if (condition)
{
    @:</div>
}
```

I Thought it should do the job.
But the problem is the browser closes the outer div before putting the inner div in it.

[image]

Comment: Is the '@' needed in these sentences?  @:<div class="wrapper-class">

Comment: That is shortend version for @Html.Raw("your html in here"). this is used in Razor pages and mvc and works like it should be. but in blazor somehow the tag closes before the next html peace is rendered.

Comment: I think the problem is in the Razor pre-compiler.  When I've encountered this I've either coded it out longhand `@if ....  else ....` or written written C# code using the RenderTreeBuilder.

Comment: This question needs to be made more clear - you are rejecting answers that are perfectly valid because they don't meet criteria that you have not included in the question.

Comment: Mrc Thats one way to go but that would make the code realy ugly. So i went with the BuildRenderTree

Comment: @MisterMagoo My question was clear the inner div is static the outer div is dynamic. the answer was about a static wrapper and dynamic inner div. I specificaly said the If else method doesnt work in this situation because the If or the else isn't determined by me but the value of somewhere else.

Comment: I don't get the problem with always having the wrapper div, but just removing the class `wrapper`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `BuildRenderTree`

With BuilderRenderTree you have full control to build component html.

For more information read this good article [Building Components Manually via RenderTreeBuilder](https://chrissainty.com/building-components-via-rendertreebuilder/)

Comment: Thanks I did finaly do this. but its a shame that the Html.Raw function doesnt work on blazor. i mean it only has one job and it is added in blazor. so why its not working. i hope it gets fixed soon.

Comment: Good news. 
Html.Raw automatically fix the error of html. that's internal functionality and I think its good way to control the html output. in high customization you have to use BuilderRenderTree.

Comment: Would be nice to have a optional boolean at the end to have both options.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing a wrapper component similar to this to solve this problem pretty elegantly:

```
@if (Wrap)
{
    <div id="@Id" class="@Class">
        @ChildContent
    </div>
}
else
{
    @ChildContent
}
@code
{
    [Parameter] public string? Id { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string? Class { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public bool Wrap { get; set; }
}
```

It doesn't support dynamic tag types, but that would be pretty easy to create using a component implementing BuildRenderTree as mRizvandi suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a simple layout like you've described than you can make use of the `MarkupString`. The trick is understanding that `MarkupString` will automatically close any tags that are left open. Therefore you just need to build the entire string properly before trying to render it as a `MarkupString`.

```
@{ bool condition = true; }
@{ string conditionalMarkup = string.Empty; }
@if (condition)
{
    conditionalMarkup = "<div class=\"wrapper-class\">";
}

@{ conditionalMarkup += "<div class=\"inner-class\"> this must be in inner-class div and wrapped in some-class div </div>"; }

@if (condition)
{
    conditionalMarkup += "</div>";
    @((MarkupString)conditionalMarkup)
}
else
{
     @((MarkupString)conditionalMarkup)
}
```

I do this for building simple conditional markup. Usually inside of an object iteration making use of `String.Format` to fill in property values.